# RaspberryPi as PPPoE server - issue in starting ppp service

Tags: server, ppp

All,

I am trying to configure my RaspberryPi 3 B as PPPoE server (wlan 0 as wan and eth0 as lan).
The below mentioned link is used to configure the PPPoE server and all the mentioned config provided

> http://blog.itist.tw/2015/02/raspberry-pi-pppoe-connection.html

However, when starting using pppoe_start, the ppp session gets terminated with no such error

> ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR): Session 0:No such device

Any help in solving this issue is appreciated.

Logs:

```
> pi@raspberrypi-prism:~ $ uname -a Linux raspberrypi-prism 4.14.79-v7+
> #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
> 
> pi@raspberrypi-prism:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
> # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
> #mur pi for sharing wifi over ethernet
> # Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
> # For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
> 
> #allow-hotplug eth0  
> #address 192.168.2.1
> #netmask 255.255.255.0
> #network 192.168.2.0
> #broadcast 192.168.2.255
> 
> auto enxb827ebd709fc iface enxb827ebd709fc inet manual up ifconfig
> $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
> #post-up /etc/ppp/pppoe_start
> #post-down /etc/ppp/pppoe_stop
> #down ifconfig $IFACE down
> 
> # Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d: source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d pi@raspberrypi-prism:~ $ cat
> /etc/ppp/pppoe-server-options 
> # PPP options for the PPPoE server
> # LIC: GPL
> auth 
> lcp-echo-failure 3 
> lcp-echo-interval 60 
> mtu 1482 
> mru 1482
> require-chap 
> ms-dns 8.8.8.8 
> ms-dns 8.8.4.4 
> netmask 255.255.255.0
> defaultroute 
> noipdefault 
> usepeerdns 
> debug 
> logfile
> /var/log/pppoe-server-log
> 
> pi@raspberrypi-prism:~ $ sudo cat /etc/ppp/chap-secrets 
> # Secrets for authentication using CHAP
> # client  server  secret          IP addresses 
> "murpppoe"    *   "pppoeacc123"       172.32.50.12    
> 
> pi@raspberrypi-prism:~ $ sudo cat /etc/ppp/pppoe_start 
> #!/bin/bash
> ##############################
> # Simple script that starts PPPoE Server
> ##############################
> 
> # Enable IP Forwarding echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
> 
> # Start PPPoE Server pppoe-server -C murisp -L 172.32.50.1 -p /etc/ppp/ipaddress_pool -I enxb827ebd709fc -m 1412
> 
> # Set Firewall rules iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
> 
> 
> pi@raspberrypi-prism:~ $ ifconfig  enxb827ebd709fc:
> flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
>         ether b8:27:eb:d7:09:fc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
>         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
>         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
>         RX packets 247  bytes 21931 (21.4 KiB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 247  bytes 21931 (21.4 KiB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 10.196.46.55  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.196.47.255
>         inet6 fe80::dfd2:8805:ab25:b4a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>         ether b8:27:eb:82:5c:a9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 824  bytes 664303 (648.7 KiB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 827  bytes 110628 (108.0 KiB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> 
> 
> dmesg | grep -i eth [    1.955184] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register
> 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet,
> b8:27:eb:d7:09:fc [    4.059013] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 enxb827ebd709fc:
> renamed from eth0 [    9.674809] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation)
> ver 1.3
> 
>
>
> //start pppoe server
> pi@raspberrypi-prism:~ $ sudo pppoe-start
>................TIMED OUT
>
> 
> tail -f /var/log/syslog
> 
> Mar 20 15:11:38 raspberrypi-prism pppd[2730]: pppd 2.4.7 started by
> root, uid 0 Mar 20 15:11:38 raspberrypi-prism pppd[2730]: Using
> interface ppp0 Mar 20 15:11:38 raspberrypi-prism pppd[2730]: Connect:
> ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2 Mar 20 15:11:38 raspberrypi-prism pppoe[2733]:
> ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR): Session 0: No such device Mar 20 15:11:38
> raspberrypi-prism pppd[2730]: Modem hangup Mar 20 15:11:38
> raspberrypi-prism pppd[2730]: Connection terminated. Mar 20 15:11:38
> raspberrypi-prism pppd[2730]: Exit. Mar 20 15:11:38 raspberrypi-prism
> pppoe-connect: PPPoE connection lost; attempting re-connection.
> 
> 
> Mar 20 16:38:18 raspberrypi-prism dnsmasq[1000]: using nameserver
> 135.245.163.125#53 Mar 20 16:38:22 raspberrypi-prism kernel: [  233.214913] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2 Mar 20 16:38:23 raspberrypi-prism pppd[1916]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0 Mar 20
> 16:38:23 raspberrypi-prism pppd[1916]: Using interface ppp0 Mar 20
> 16:38:23 raspberrypi-prism pppd[1916]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
> Mar 20 16:38:23 raspberrypi-prism pppoe[1918]: ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR):
> Session 0: No such device Mar 20 16:38:23 raspberrypi-prism
> pppd[1916]: Modem hangup Mar 20 16:38:23 raspberrypi-prism pppd[1916]:
> Connection terminated. Mar 20 16:38:23 raspberrypi-prism pppd[1916]:
> Exit. Mar 20 16:38:23 raspberrypi-prism pppoe-connect: PPPoE
> connection lost; attempting re-connection. Mar 20 16:38:27
> raspberrypi-prism dhcpcd[335]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available Mar 20
> 16:38:28 raspberrypi-prism pppd[1944]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid
> 0 Mar 20 16:38:28 raspberrypi-prism pppd[1944]: Using interface ppp0
> Mar 20 16:38:28 raspberrypi-prism pppd[1944]: Connect: ppp0 <-->
> /dev/pts/2 Mar 20 16:38:28 raspberrypi-prism pppoe[1947]:
> ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR): Session 0: No such device Mar 20 16:38:28
> raspberrypi-prism pppd[1944]: Modem hangup Mar 20 16:38:28
> raspberrypi-prism pppd[1944]: Connection terminated. Mar 20 16:38:28
> raspberrypi-prism pppd[1944]: Exit. Mar 20 16:38:28 raspberrypi-prism
> pppoe-connect: PPPoE connection lost; attempting re-connection.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the interface for the PPPoE server. You should configure your `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
post-up /etc/ppp/pppoe_start
post-down /etc/ppp/pppoe_stop
```

Also, you need external network card.